# Android Rotation Type Sensors

Tags: android, android-service, android-sensors

So I've done a bit of research on Android's Rotation-type sensors, but I'm still having trouble understanding them.

Android has the following Rotation-type sensors:

1. Rotation Vector
2. Game Rotation Vector
3. Geomagnetic Rotation Vector

Different sources are providing different information.

The Android sensors document isn't too specific, but it seems that Game Rotation Vector is like Rotation Vector except that it doesn't use the magnetometer. This means that Rotation Vector does use the magnetometer... does that mean that Rotation Vector and Geomagnetic Rotation Vector are the same thing?

If so then then why are there two different versions?

It would be great if someone could shed a little light on this, thanks.

UPDATE: Below is the link for the Android documentation that provides an overview of the 3 rotation sensors. Again, all 3 are listed, but the documentation isn't specific as to what is the difference between them.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html

Answer (score 0):

The Docs over the Geomagnetic Rotation Vector Sensor says:

> The geomagnetic rotation vector sensor is similar to the Rotation Vector Sensor, but it uses a magnetometer instead of a gyroscope.

I think there is a mistake with "instead of a gyroscope".

My guess is, that

1. the Rotation Vector Sensor uses the Geomagnetic Field Sensor
2. the Geomagnetic Rotation Vector Sensor uses the Uncalibrated Magnetometer and
3. the Game Rotation Vector Sensor uses some other reference

Maybe they have changed their docs:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-geomrot